# Cannot set 'quality' on Expo Camera recordAsync

Tags: react-native, expo

SDK Version: 37

Platforms: Android

I’ve been trying to set ‘quality’ on Camera.RecordAsync but nothing is working. My file size for only 30 seconds recording is ~21MB (this is quite high compared to 7MB on iOS for the same config)

Here is my code:

```
await this.camera.recordAsync({
maxDuration: 30000,
quality: Platform.OS === ‘android’ ? ‘4:3’ : Camera.Constants.VideoQuality[‘480p’],
orientation: ‘portrait’
});
```

I’ve also used [‘480p’] for Android, no luck at all.

pls help. Any value that might work for Android? you’d save my life.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to set it this way:

```
quality: Camera.Constants.VideoQuality["4:3"],
```